# a question about weakly $p$-Cauchy sequences

Tags: functional-analysis

A sequence $(x_n)$ in a Banach space $X$ is weakly $p$-convergent to $x\in X$ if the sequence $(x_n-x)$ is weakly $p$-summable.

A sequence $(x_n)$ in a Banach space $X$ is weakly $p$-Cauchy if for any increasing sequences $(k_n)$ and $(j_n)$ of positive integrers, the sequence $(x_{k_n}-x_{j_n})$ is weakly $p$-summable.

Question: Is it true that if $(x_n)$ is a weakly $p$-Cauchy sequence in $X$ and it is relatively weakly compact, then $(x_n)$ is weakly $p$-convergent?

Let $(x_n)$ be as above. Since it is weakly Cauchy and relatively weakly compact, it is weakly convergent to some $x\in X$. Let $y_n=x_n-x$. Then $(y_n)$ is weakly $p$-Cauchy and weakly null. If it is weakly $p$-summable, then $(x_n)$ is weakly $p$-convergent to $x$. Thus it is enough to show that a weakly $p$-Cauchy sequence which is weakly null is weakly $p$-summable.

Answer (score 1):

Observation 1. Let $1<p<\infty$. If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then
$$ |a+b|^p\le 2^{p-1}(|a|^p+|b|^p).$$

Indeed, the function $h(x)=|x|^p$ is convex for $x>0$, and thus
$$\left|\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b\right|^p\le \left|\frac{1}{2}|a|+\frac{1}{2}|b|\right|^p\le \frac{1}{2}|a|^p+\frac{1}{2}|b|^p. $$
This implies the above inequality.

Let $(y_n)$ be weakly $p$-Cauchy and weakly null. We show that it is weakly $p$-summable.
By contradiction, suppose that $(y_n)$ is not weakly $p$-summable. Let $\epsilon>0$ and $y^*\in Y^*$ such that for every $N$, there exist $n, m\ge N$ with $\sum_{i=n+1}^m |y^*(y_i)|^p >\epsilon $.

Let $N=1$ and $n_1\ge 1$, $n_2>n_1+1$ such that

\begin{equation}  \label{eq:a1}
\sum_{n=n_1+1}^{n_2}  |y^*(y_{n})|^p> \epsilon.
\end{equation}

Since $y^*(y_n)\to 0$, there is $N_1$ such that for each $j\ge N_1$,
$|y^*(y_j)|^p< \frac{\epsilon}{2^p(n_2-n_1)}$.
Therefore if $j_1\ge N_1$,
\begin{equation}  \label{eq:a2}
2^{p-1}\sum_{n=j_1+1}^{j_1+n_2-n_1} |y^*(y_n)|^p<\frac{\epsilon}{2}. 
\end{equation}
Note that $ n_1+1<n_1+2<\ldots <n_2 $ and $  j_1+1<j_1+2<\ldots< j_1+n_2-n_1  $.

Then we have
\begin{equation}  \label{eq:a3}
\left(|y^*(y_{n_1+1})|^p-2^{p-1} |y^*(y_{j_1+1})|^p\right)
+\ldots+ \left(|y^*(y_{n_2})|^p-2^{p-1} |y^*(y_{j_1+n_2-n_1})|^p\right)> \frac{\epsilon}{2}. 
\end{equation}

By the previous inequality and Observation 1 it follows that
$$
2^{p-1} |y^*(y_{n_1+1})-y^*(y_{j_1+1})|^p+\ldots+ 2^{p-1}|y^*(y_{n_2})-y^*(y_{j_1+n_2-n_1})|^p> \frac{\epsilon}{2}. 
$$

Then
$$ 
|y^*(y_{n_1+1})-y^*(y_{j_1+1})|^p
+ \ldots+ |y^*(y_{n_2})-y^*(y_{j_1+n_2-n_1})|^p> \frac{\epsilon}{2^p}. 
$$

Let $N=n_2+1$ and $n_3> n_2+1$, $n_4>n_3$ such that
\begin{equation}  \label{eq:a5}
\sum_{n=n_3+1}^{n_4}  |y^*(y_{n})|^p> \epsilon.
\end{equation}

Since $y^*(y_n)\to 0$, there is $N_2$ such that for each $j\ge N_2$,
$|y^*(y_j)|^p< \frac{\epsilon}{2^p(n_4-n_3)}$.
Therefore if $j_2 \ge \max\{N_1, j_1+n_2-n_1\}-1$,
\begin{equation}  \label{eq:a6}
2^{p-1}\sum_{n=j_2+1}^{j_2+n_4-n_3} |y^*(y_n)|^p<\frac{\epsilon}{2}. 
\end{equation}

By the previous two inequalities and Observation 1, it follows that
$$ 
|y^*(y_{n_3+1})-y^*(y_{j_2+1})|^p
+ \ldots+ |y^*(y_{n_4})-y^*(y_{j_2+n_4-n_3})|^p> \frac{\epsilon}{2^p}. 
$$
Note that
$$ n_1+1<n_1+2<\ldots < n_2< n_3+1< \ldots <n_4$$
and
$$  j_1+1<j_1+2<\ldots < j_1+n_2-n_1 < j_2+1< j_2+2< \ldots <j_2+n_4-n_3. $$
Continuining by induction we obtain two increasing sequences $(n_k+m)$ and $(j_{k-1}+m$ such that
$(y^*(y_{n_k+m} -y_{j_{k-1}+m}))$ is not weakly $p$-summable. This contradicts the fact that $(y_n)$ is weakly $p$-Cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

A Banach space $X$ is called weakly sequentially complete of order $p$ if every weakly $p$-Cauchy sequence in $X$ is weakly $p$-convergent.

This might be an example like you are asking.

By Theorem 2.18 in the paper below, if $1<p<2$ and $X$ has property $p$-$(V^*)$, then $X$ is weakly sequentially complete of order $p$.

By Theorem 2.14 in the same paper, the James $p$-space $J_p$ ($1<p<\infty$) has property $p$-$(V^*)$.

Then the James $p$-space $J_p$ ($1<p<2$) is weakly sequentially complete of order $p$. Also, this space is not weakly sequentially complete (WSC) (paper, p.421).

L. Li, D. Chen, and J. Alejandro Chavez-Dominguez, Pe{\l}czy'nski's Property $(V^*)$ of order $p$ and its quantification, Math. Nach. 291 (2018), 420---442.

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.201600335

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n)$ in $X$ be weakly null and weakly $p$-Cauchy for some $1\leq p<\infty$. Let $f\in X^*$ be arbitrary. Since $f(x_n)\to 0$, $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N} \hspace{4mm} \exists k_n\geq n \hspace{4mm} |f(x_{k_n})|\leq n^{-2/p}$$ We may iteratively select $k_n$ so that $(k_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an increasing sequence. Thus, for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^m |f(x_n)|^p\right)^{1/p} 
\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^m |f(x_n)-f(x_{k_n})|^p\right)^{1/p} + \left(\sum_{n=1}^m |f(x_{k_n})|^p\right)^{1/p} \\
\leq \left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |f(x_n-x_{k_n})|^p\right)^{1/p} + \left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)^{1/p} 
$$
so $(f(x_n))\in\ell^p$. Since $f\in X^*$ was arbitrary, $(x_n)$ is weakly $p$-summable.

Along the same lines, if $(x_n)$ is any weakly $p$-Cauchy sequence, then $(x_n)$ is weakly Cauchy so $x_n\to\mu\in X^{**}$ converges weak$^*$ in $X^{**}$. The series
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |f(x_n)-\mu(f)|^p 
$$
can be shown the converge for each $f\in X^*$ verbatim similarly as above. Thus, trivially, if $X$ is weakly sequentially complete (WSC), then every $p$-Cauchy sequence is $p$-convergent in $X$ (perhaps called $p$-WSC ?).

Comment: Thank you very much. How about the following proof by contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

In the first proof, can we also do this?

Let $(y_n)$ be weakly $p$-Cauchy and weakly null in $Y$. Let $y^*\in Y^*$. Since
$y^*(y_n)\to 0$, there exists $k_n\ge n$ such that $|y^*(y_{k_n})|< \frac{1}{n^{2/p}}$.
(Find a subsequence which is weakly $p$-summable)

Then
$$\left(\sum_n |y^*(y_n)|^p \right)^{1/p}\le 
\left(\sum_n |y^*(y_n-y_{k_n})|^p\right)^{1/p}+\left(\sum_n |y^*(y_{k_n})|^p\right)^{1/p}<\infty. 
$$
Thus $(y_n)$ is weakly $p$-summable.

Comment: Sorry for bothering with relatively unimportant menial details, but generally the subsequence $(y_{k_n})$ may not be weakly p-summable. A Banach space X has property $S_r$ if every weakly null sequence in X has a weakly p-summable subsequence, where $(p-1)(r-1)=1$ , e.g. Definitions 48 & 54 in https://books.google.ca/books?id=9RHoBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA152